# Knockout: Remove Array Item from Computed Observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a `computed` variable which contains array. Something like this:

```
self.MyArray = ko.computed(function() {
    var source = [];
    // Some Logic to Prepare Array
    ...
    ...
    ...

    return source;
});
```

Now On a button click event, I want to remove Item from `self.MyArray`. But I could not find any feasible solution for this.

I tried with this:

```
self.MyArray.remove(currentRow);
```

But it throws exception:

> Uncaught TypeError: self.MyArray.remove is not a function

Sample Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spidercode/afmn2keb/)

Comment: Can you add the source of the computed to the question?

Comment: @Nisarg Shah, the source of the computed is irrelevant. Refer to [the MCVE page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @NisargShah: I have added fiddle in my question

Comment: @user2988458 You have declared an observable and a computed by the same name. That means the computed will overwrite the observable array. Also, can you expand on the purpose of making `DataSource` a computed variable rather than an observable array?

Comment: @NisargShah: My `DataSource` relies on other `ObservableArray`s. If the value of these `ObservableArrays` changed, my `DataSource` should be updated based on changed values in array.

Answer (score 0):

### Regular Array

You're returning a regular array, not a knockout observableArray. A standard javascript array does not have a remove function. In the following example, I've used a generic remove function to solve your problem.

```js
var bar = "foo";

self.MyArray = ko.computed(function() {
    var source = [];
    source.push(bar);
    return source;
});

function remove(array, element) {
    const index = array.indexOf(element);
    
    if (index !== -1) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

console.log(self.MyArray()); // ["foo"]

remove(self.MyArray(), bar);

console.log(self.MyArray()); // []
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

### Knockout ObservableArray

If you want to use an observableArray instead, you don't need the extra remove function. A knockout observableArray already has one. The example below shows how you can remove it.

```js
var bar = "foo";

self.MyArray = ko.computed(function() {
    var source = ko.observableArray();
    source.push(bar);
    return source;
});

console.log(ko.unwrap(self.MyArray())); // ["foo"]

self.MyArray().remove(bar);

console.log(ko.unwrap(self.MyArray())); // []
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if I return `ObservableArray() ` ? Will it work ?

Comment: Included the `observableArray()` remove function in my answer.

Comment: This will not work when I have to bind this array in `DOM`. I have created sample fiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/spidercode/afmn2keb/

Comment: It does work. Pay more attention to unwrapping the computed value. You can't access it using just `DataSource`. You need to use `DataSource()`.

Comment: Just checked your fiddle again, and there are a lot of errors. Don't use the text binding on an input field, use textInput or value instead. Don't use a for loop to remove the item, the remove function takes an element as a parameter and does the work for you. Plus a lot of unwrapping errors. I tried to understand what you were trying to do and edited your fiddle to match my understanding. http://jsfiddle.net/uj65ekbz/2/

Answer (score 0):

There are several changes required for the code to work. I've listed below the important ones:

1. The binding for `Name` input must be two-way to allow the `Add` button to push the text to the `NameList` array. You could either use `textInput` or `value` binding for this, instead of the `text` binding.

   ```
   <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: Name">
   ```
2. While adding a new item to the array, since it is an observable it must be accessed as `self.NameList.push(self.Name());`, rather than `self.NameList.push(self.Name);`.
3. Inside the remove function, you can get the index of the source element, and then remove it. Something like:

   ```
   var idx = self.DataSource().indexOf(selectedData);
   self.NameList.splice(idx, 1);
   ```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afmn2keb/7/

Comment: Agree with first two points. But in 3rd point you have used `splice` on `NameList`. Instead of that I would like to remove from `DataSource` only without affecting `NameList`.

Comment: @user2988458 Then you can just add a toggling property that controls whether or not the item goes through to `DataSource` or not. On `Remove` you can just set the property to `false`.